# how to send commands to web terminal?

Tags: python-3.x, tornado, xtermjs

**here is my code**
  It only creates terminal on web using 'bash' command.
I want to add functionality to this code similar to the interactive labs work. Which has terminal on one side and content part on other side. I want to run command on mouseclick function to my web terminal, and I am searching for solution how to do that can you suggest something?

```
class WebmuxTermManager(terminado.SingleTermManager):
def get_terminal(self, port_number):
    self.shell_command = ["bash"]
    term = self.new_terminal()
    self.start_reading(term)
    return term

class TerminalPageHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
def get_host(self, port_number):
    pass

def get(self, port_number):
    return self.render("term.html", static=self.static_url, ws_url_path="/_websocket/"+port_number, hostname=self.get_host(port_number))

if __name__ == "__main__":

term_manager = WebmuxTermManager(shell_command=('bash'))
handlers = [
    (r"/_websocket/(\w+)", terminado.TermSocket, {'term_manager': term_manager}),
    (r"/shell/([\d]+)/?", TerminalPageHandler),
    (r"/webmux_static/(.*)", tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {'path':os.path.join(TEMPLATE_DIR,"webmux_static")}),
]
application = tornado.web.Application(handlers, static_path=STATIC_DIR,template_path=TEMPLATE_DIR,term_manager=term_manager,debug=True)
application.listen(8888)


try:
    IOLoop.current().start()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    logging.info("\nShuttiing down")
finally:
    term_manager.shutdown()
    IOLoop.current().close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I dont know what terminado is, so I will stick to tornado's websockets,

Make a websocket class to send and recieve messages as per your ruleset

```
class WebsocketHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def check_origin(self, origin):
        # deals with allowing certain ip address ranges or domain_names to
        # connect to your websocket

        pass

    def open(self):
        # perform some logic when the socket is connected to the client side
        # eg give it a unique id to and append it to a list etc, its up to you

        pass

    def on_message(self, command):
        # this is where your problem lies
        # act on the message
        send_back = self.runCommand(command)
        self.write_message(send_back)

   def on_close(self):
       # delete the socket

       pass

   def runCommand(self, command):
       # import shlex
       # import supbrocess
       cmd = shlex.split(command)
       process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
       stdout, stderr = process.communicate()

       return dict(
           stdout=stdout.decode(),
           stderr=stdout.decode()
       )
```

The route for *WebsocketHandler* class is

```
(r"/websocket_test", WebsocketHandler)
```

Hook it up to your routes and start the tornado server

**On the client side**

Connect using javascript as follows:

```
//secure or unsecure, up to you.

unsecure_test_conn = new WebSocket('ws://ip_address_or_domain_name/websocket_test')
secure_test_conn = new WebSocket('wss://ip_address_or_domain_name/websocket_test')

unsecure_test_conn.onmessage = function(event){
    data = JSON.parse(event.data)
    //act on the data as you see fit and probably send it back to server
    send_back = parseMessage(data)
    unsecure_test_conn.send(send_back)
}
```

This should get you started on how to send information back and forth on the web.

Comment: Thank you for your ans but the flow of data is already bidirection. That means I am able to execute commands through my web terminal. And output is also fine. The thing is that I need to add functionality in such a way that after clicking on any command on browser the command should copy and get execute on the terminal.

Comment: I have added the runCommand method, with that you will run commands as if it were a terminal. Using the subprocess module.